# Hibernate full text search using hibernate-search-4.1.1.Final.jar but having error like query builder can not resolved

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have facing error at query builder can not be typed and **org.apache.lucene** not found.

I will added all jar related to spring-mvc and hibernate

```
@Repository
public class SearchDAO {
    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    public List<SearchVO> viewSeachResult(String searchText) throws Exception
     {
      try
      {
        Session s= this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        //Session s= HibernateUtil.getSession();
        FullTextSession text = Search.getFullTextSession(s);

        // create native Lucene query unsing the query DSL
        // alternatively you can write the Lucene query using the Lucenquery
        // parser
        // or the Lucene programmatic API. The Hibernate Search DSL is
        // recommended though

        QueryBuilder qb =     text.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(SearchVO.class).get();

        org.apache.lucene.search.Query query= qb.keyWord().onFields("Description","Title","Author","Area").matching(searchText).createQuery();

        org.hibernate.Query hibQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query,SearchVO.class);
        List<SearchVO> result= hibQuery.list();
        return result;
      }catch(Exception e)
      {
        throw e;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you add the jar for org.apache.lucene ? add you pom file to the question

Comment: yes i added the jar  of org.apache.lucene and i am not using Maven so there is no pom file

Comment: still errors? can you post the stack trace of the error? `caused by` what part

Comment: where i declare QueryBuilder at that line it give me a error that QueryBuilder can not resolved to a type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You need [hibernate-search jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-search/).

The jars that required are mentioned [here](http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

You can manually download from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/hibernate-search.htm).

Hope this helps.